# How can I make an prototype ajax request with an array of values as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

i'm trying to make a ajax update in prototype with some values from a multirecordselect that sends a requests like.

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"use_campaign", "campaigns"=> ["27929","27932"] , "advertiser_id"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/reporting", "ad_id"=>""}
```

as you can see the request sends the "campaigns" elements as an array of values, i'm trying to do the same with this js code over prototype 7.

```
// get the campaigns 
var campaign_ids = {}; 
var campaigns = $('filter_form').getInputs("hidden","report[campaigns][]"); 
campaigns.each( function(field) {
             campaign_ids.push(field.value); 
}); 

new Ajax.Updater('ad_filter', '/admin/reporting/use_campaign', {
                method : 'get',
                asynchronous : true,
                evalScripts : true,
                parameters : {
                    'advertiser_id' : $('filter_form')['report[advertiser_id]'].value,
                    'ad_id' : $('filter_form')['report[ad_id]'].value,
                    'campaigns' : campaign_ids
                }
 });
```

the campaigns_ids is getting the correct info as an array like:

```
[ "27929", "27932" ]
```

but seems that prototype ajax update is sending a request like:

```
http://my_domain/admin/reporting/use_campaign?ad_id=&advertiser_id=&campaigns=27929&campaigns=27932
```

what sends parameters like:

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"use_campaign", "campaigns"=> "27929" , "advertiser_id"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/reporting", "ad_id"=>""}
```

I also tryed with

```
Object.toJSON(campaign_ids)
```

but i only get an escaped string like

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"use_campaign", "campaigns"=>"[\"27929\",\"27932\"]" , "advertiser_id"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/reporting", "ad_id"=>""}
```

There is anyway to do this as I wish?

Thanks for all.

Comment: ok stupid me, just put the right parameter 'campaigns[]' instead of 'campaigns' . Sorry for ask =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you use PHP as a back-end framework.
To make sure PHP understands array-like GET parameters, you [need to add](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16195) a `[]` to the parameter name:

```
          parameters : {
                //...
                'campaigns[]' : campaign_ids
            }
```

Comment: thanks I have resolved it and posted like a comment as stackoverflow dosen't let me answer myself... thak's anyway. I'm using rails anyway =)

Comment: Ah, interesting. Looks like RoR suffers from the same issue.